# CSS/HTML Weird LI spacing

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML5 header setup. It uses `<ul>` and `<li>` elements for the links.

This is the HTML:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <a href="/"><li id="logoli"><img src="/assets/logo.png" id="logo"></li></a>
            <a href="/"><li>Home</li></a>
            <a href="/"><li class="5px">Roulette</li></a>
            <a href="/"><li>Free Stuff</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

And the CSS:

```
header {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
nav {    
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
    color: #0077C5;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
li {
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 65px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
        display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
#logo {
    height: 50px;
}
#logoli {
    padding-top: 7px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

For some reason this happens: https://image.prntscr.com/image/w0LAMn5qRMq0OqIAfDTsHw.png
If you look at the nav bar you can easily see that the first two elements have a normal amount of spacing in-between. But the seccond and third have weirdly small spacing. I used inspect element on the `<li>`'s but they are all the same height. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some HTML and CSS Fixes, Wrap the `anchors` in `li` elements and the issue was you have mentioned a width to the `li`, which causes this wierd spacing.

HTML

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li id="logoli">
              <a href="/"><img src="/assets/logo.png" id="logo"></a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="5px"><a href="/">Roulette</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Free Stuff</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
nav {    
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
    color: #0077C5;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
li {
    line-height: 65px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
#logo {
    height: 50px;
}
#logoli {
    padding-top: 7px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're explicitly defining a width on your list items. Remove the width and separate the list items with padding instead. Optionally, remove any padding on the last list item, since you won't need it.

```
li {
    /* width: 100px; */
    padding-right: 1em;
    line-height: 65px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

li:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eulloa/yx7vkt79/

Also, restructure your list items so that they are the parent element of your anchors, not the other way around.

```
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li> <!-- structure your list items this way -->

<a href="/"><li>Home</li></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `<a href>`'s inside the `<li>` tags like this:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li id="logoli"><a href="/"><img src="/assets/logo.png" id="logo"></a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Roulette</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Free Stuff</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Also - you have a `class="5px"` on one of the `<li>`'s, but that class isn't in your CSS. You should make your `<li>`'s a fixed width and center the text, or use a standard padding on the left and right of the `<li>` text to maintain a uniform spacing rather than injecting classes to push single elements around.